# Invaild Grant issue in Xero OAuth2.0 Refresh token

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I'm using Xero OAuth2.0 APIs, I am refreshing token once token is expired.
[Xero Documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow)
I'm storing token in JSON file so i can retrive next time.

Erorr Response:

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Please refer below code i've used

```
public function getAccessToken($code = null) {
    if(file_exists($this->tokenPath) && isset($code)) {
        $accessToken = $this->getAccessTokenFromAuthCode($code);
    } else if (file_exists($this->tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = $this->getAccessTokenFromJSON();
        try {
            if (time() > $accessToken->expires) {
                $accessToken = $this->provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
                    'refresh_token' => $accessToken->refresh_token
                ]);
            }
        } catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
            //header('Location: ' . $this->getAuthorizationUrl());
        }

    } else if(isset($code)){
        $accessToken = $this->getAccessTokenFromAuthCode($code);
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $this->getAuthorizationUrl());
    }

    return $accessToken;
}

public function getAccessTokenFromAuthCode($code) {
    return $this->storeAccessTokenToJSON($this->provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', ['code' => $code]));
}

public function getAccessTokenFromJSON(){

    return json_decode(file_get_contents($this->tokenPath));
}

public function storeAccessTokenToJSON($accessToken){
    file_put_contents($this->tokenPath, json_encode($accessToken));

    return json_decode(file_get_contents($this->tokenPath));
}
```

Comment: Check if the configuration you have given in the app matches the configurations you used to generate the initial file.

Answer (score 3):

The expiration for an access token is `30 minutes`. And Unused refresh tokens expire after `60 days.` If you don’t refresh your access token within 60 days the user will need to reauthorize your app.

- If you perform a token refresh successfully you get a ***`new refresh token`*** with the ***new access token***
- If for whatever reason, you don't receive the response after performing the token refresh you can retry refreshing the old token for a grace period of 30 minutes

> ```
> $curl = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
>   CURLOPT_URL => "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token?=",
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
>   CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
>   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
>   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
>   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
>   CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
>   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
>   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
>  'XXXXXXXXXXXXX','client_secret' =>
>  'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'),
>   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
>     "grant_type: refresh_token",
>     "Content-Type: application/json",
>      ),
> ));
>
> $response = curl_exec($curl);
>
> curl_close($curl);
> echo $response;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the 'offline_access' scope when you got your initial token?

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/scopes#offline-access

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score -1):

Invalid_grant is the standard error response code when a refresh token has expired.

Common token lifetimes are something like:
* Access token = 60 minutes
* Refresh token = 8 hours

When the refresh token expired you have to get the user to log in again.

Comment: According to the docs, https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow, "Your app can refresh an access token without user interaction by using a refresh token". This appears to be broken.